# Why is my webpage half the size in browser than it is on hard drive?

Tags: networking, browser, webserver

My webpage with all its assets is 1.7MB on disk. And only 700kb in chrome dev tool (network tab). For instance, my 140kb css is now, according to google, only 26kb heavy. Same for my js bundle, it goes from 330 kb to 90. Also, I was testing on a private session so no browser caching.

Response headers that I can see on chrome :

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Wed, 30 Sep 2015 14:25:35 GMT
ETag:"e621f4-42c5-520f72d888210"
Keep-Alive:timeout=3, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

[image: network timeline]

[image: real size]

[image: gzip issue]

Comment: How are you accessing the website? Is it hosted on a server or are you opening it locally?

Comment: it's on a local php 5.3 server

Comment: Does your server support gzip compression?

Comment: Which server are you using?  Apache?  Nginx?

Comment: A screenshot of your devtools Network Timeline would be super useful...

Comment: I added a screenshot but I had to hide some file names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not seeing everything in your dev tools.

Don't use small request rows or else you will ONLY see the gzipped size of your web files.

1. The gzipped file size sent from the server
2. Your browser extracted the gzipped file and it contains this many KB

[image]

---

The reason that your images are showing a larger compression size is because PNG and JPG is a compressed format so your web server is actually creating unnecessary overhead by attempting to re-compress it and that extra overhead is being translated to both wasted CPU time and additional KB.

If you are running Apache and have access to `httpd.conf` then I would suggest adding a line to it that looks like this:

```
# Don't compress these images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|jpg|ico|png) no-gzip dont-vary
```

This holds true for images that are already heavily optimized and compressed.

In my screenshot you can see that 1+2 are larger and unoptimized images but 3.jpg is already down to bare-bones so the compression did not help #3 but it did help 1+2:

[image]

Comment: yes indeed, now I can see both values. But for files like images and fonts, the first value is always higher than the second value.. for js and css its the opposite

Comment: @topleft Well that's weird, can you update your question with another screenshot?

Comment: I updated the screen, as you can see the values seem strange?

Comment: @topleft Thanks, please take a look at my updated answer

Comment: I understand the problem now thanks. But then wouldn't your images be the same size in both lines ? I can see it is not the case in your screenshot

Comment: @topleft sorry about that, check out the edit now.

Comment: @topleft Here is an article which discusses web server compression: http://www.itworld.com/article/2693941/cloud-computing/why-it-doesn-t-make-sense-to-gzip-all-content-from-your-web-server.html and this one http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/gzipped-images-is-it-worth

Comment: alright, so considering I'm a good front end dev and all my image files are always compressed to the max, I need to tell my sys admin to remove gzip compression for images, to sum up ?

Comment: @topleft basically, yes. PDFs as well. Check out the links I posted in my last comment as well.